# External Js object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to include the `viewerjs` lib in my react project but I just can't get to a point where I can declare an object of the class.

I have tried creating script tag in `componentDidMount` but still says `Viewer` not defined. `window.Viewer` doesn't work either.

I have tried initializing `Viewer` object in the `onload` event of the script tag still no luck

I have tried:

```
var Viewer = require('../_thirdparty/viewer.js');
```

or

```
var Viewer = require('../_thirdparty/viewer.js').Viewer;
```

No luck.

Now I really need to insert it from local project as well because I have made a few modification in the viewerjs code, I know, I know not a good practice, but otherwise I'll have to rewrite the entire code myself.

Does anyone know of a way.

In my `componentDidMount` I just want to be able to write:

```
this.viewer = new Viewer(this._images, options);
```

and it to work like normal.

Comment: If the library you mean is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/viewerjs), why don't you load it like any other npm package i.e. `npm i viewerjs` and import it like `import Viewer from 'viewerjs'`?

Comment: Indeed; works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-dew-rut5c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes that is what I am using for now but like I said U am trying to losd a modified viewerjs code, which npm mofule doesn’t have

Comment: Only other option is to overwrite each function I have modified which is the correct way to go about it but It will be too much code in my component. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I've updated the sandbox to use viewer.esm.js and viewer.css from the repository.

Comment: Wow thanks Chris, this is perfect. Had no idea what esm.js files were meant for.